# How do zero values affect the correlation between two twitter activity time series?

Tags: correlation, zero-inflation, pearson-r, social-network, spurious-correlation

I have a time series of Twitter activities (lets call it time series 0) from which I extract two separate time series based on different sets of users (i.e. time series 1 contains the activity of a subset of users and time series 2 contains the activity of the remaining users - see table 1). I want to calculate cross correlation between time series 1 and 2.

To create the time series I resample the original list of Tweets based on a given time step (e.g. 1 h) and sum all the tweets that were made in this interval:

| Time | time series 0 | time series 1 | time series 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 01:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 03:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 04:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 05:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 06:00 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 07:00 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 08:00 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 09:00 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 100:00 | 15 | 10 | 5 |

(This table is just an example, the original data is aggregated at a 10 minute interval and contains over 30 000 time steps and roughly 10 000 zero values in time series 0).

This leads to a large amount of zero values in the dataset and the data are power law distributed (see fig. 1). I use only the decomposed residuals of the time series (removing trend and seasonality) and transform the data by applying log(x+1) (+1 because otherwise the zero values would give -inf). Afterwards in order to reduce noise I delete values below a given threshold and then split up the datasets given a previously derived set of user into my new time series 1 and 2. Finally I calculate the Pearson correlation for multiple lags between time series 1 and 2.

**Now to my question:**
It seems like the more zero values I keep, I get a very sharp increase of the correlation value from time lag 0 to time lag 1 between time series 1 and 2 (see fig. 2). Can someone possibly explain where this behaviour comes from or encountered something similar? The peak remains when I resample the data on a different interval for example 30 min or 1h). I saw [in this post](https://tonyladson.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/spurious-correlation-between-skewed-independent-variables/#:%7E:text=The%20main%20message%20is%20that,association%20between%20the%20variables%20concerned%E2%80%9D.) that there might be spurious correlations between skewed data - can anyone give some general intuition where this comes from?

[image]

**Figure 1** shows the power law distribution of the original dataset activity (time series 0).

[image]

**Figure 2** shows the cross-correlation plot where

- the black curve represents the correlation of the time series 0 with itself (i.e. at time lag 0 = autocorrelation)
- and the other three curves represent correlations
  between the subsets of time series 0 - i.e. time series 1 and 2, where the time series were derived for different subsets of users (blue = random sample of users, red and green = systematically derived subset of users).
  The left plot contains all original values and the right plot only contains time steps were activity in time series 0 was highest.

[image]

**Figure 3** shows the scatter plots at time lag 1 that correspond to figure 2. One can see that the amount of zero values in the left plot is way higher.